# Show location details in Google maps javascript api v3

Tags: php, google-maps

I am displaying the google map using javascript api v3. I am now able to display the title on mouse over of the pin.But I want to display the details in a div on mouse over of the pin.Can anyone suggest a method for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `details` holds the information to display, `marker` is the pin to click and `map` is your map:

```
var contentDetails = "<div>" + details + "</div>"
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( {content: contentDetails});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Comment: Can I show contentDetails over the marker on clicking a button outside the map?